# Python BeautifulSoup web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Hi i am new to both python and web scraping following is my script to get the URLs from the website but I got stuck in between I cant get the urls from the class tag if I inspect the website I can see the URL but in my script it shows as javascript [This is the link](https://www.northcoastelectric.com/Products) 
any help, please
thanks in advance

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.northcoastelectric.com/Products"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
something = soup.find(class_="clearAfter")
print(chips)
for i in something:
   new_url = i.a["href"]
   print(new_url)`
```

Comment: What URLs specifically? Can you give a sample of what you need

Comment: I need the product URLs which is present in the website like there is a product Automation and motor control I need the URLs of all the products in that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `find_all` class with `cimm_categoryItemBlock` instead of `clearAfter` because that is the class name of the `li` containing the products' links

```
something = soup.find_all(class_="cimm_categoryItemBlock")
for i in something:
    new_url = i.a.get("href")
    print(new_url)
```

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: I got the result using your code. Can you tell me why my code went wrong with this line of code   "chips = soup.find(class_="clearAfter").find_all('li')
for i in chips:
    potato = i.a["href"]
    print(potato)"

Comment: Beacause `find()` only returns the first element found but `find_all()` returns all elements with that class

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go another layer deep. Try this:

```
something = soup.find(class_="clearAfter").findNext("clearAfter")
```

Just keep adding on "findNext"commands exactly like above to the 'something' variable (assuming the class name is the same for each link)and you'll get to the links.

Remember: Beautifulsoup (and HTML) can have many branches. When you create an instance of Beautifulsoup, the common vernacular is that you you are creating a new "tree". So, if all else fails? Just create another instance and try a different branch/a different way (you likely will not need that here) and you'll be golden. HTML can get very embedded.

Otherwise, you could use selenium.  Super easy:

Just use the selenium command to  collect all the classes on a page by name (in your case, clearAfter), iterate over it, append to a list and grab the href's via "get_attribute" method. Here's an example of how I used selenium to do this.

```
    def get_results(self):
        cv = []
        bbb = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('user-name') ## self.driver is my Chromedriver webdriver used to manipulate the browser. Let me know if you have Qs!

    for plink in bbb:
           cv.append(plink.find_element_by_css_selector(
                              'a').get_attribute('href'))
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thank you, Aaron Brandhagen but the previous answer fixed the issue